# How to disable escape button in mdbreact modal for not closing modal

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

I don't want close modal / popup on the escape button in mdbreact npm. I have used keyboard={false} but it's not working.

```
   keyboard={false}
   modalOptions={{ dismissible: true }}

   <MDBModal
     isOpen={this.state.modalOuterAddNode} 
     toggle={this.toggleModalouterAddNodePopup}
     backdrop={false}
     keyboard={false}
     modalOptions={{ dismissible: true }}
   >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
}


// RENDER METHOD

<MDBModal
  //...YOUR PROPS
  onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this code is not working. Debugger doesn't goes in that function.